# Como copiar um repeater na mesma página

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho um repeater control com dados preenchidos em uma pagina aspx, na mesma pagina tem o modal, o modal aparece ao clicar em um botão. Como reuso o mesmo repeater pra listar no modal?

Repeater:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptPagamentos" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptPagamentos_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="contexto">
                <span class="font00">Tipo: </span><span class="font01">
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltTipoPagamento" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </span>
                <br />

                <span class="font00">Parcelas: </span><span class="font01">
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltParcelasPagamento" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </span>
                <br />
                <span class="font00">Valor: </span><span class="font01">
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltValorPagamento" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <span class="linha-busca"></span>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Modal

```
  <div class="modal fade open" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <b>Pedido enviado com sucesso!</b>
                <span><strong>Pedido: </strong></span>
                <asp:Literal ID="LtSeqModal" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               QUERO O REPEATER AQUI
               QUERO O REPEATER AQUI
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <div class="col-sm-12" align="center">

                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">Ok</asp:LinkButton>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Como usar o mesmo repeater na mesma página dentro do modal?

Comment: Você quer exibir os dados do Repetear no Modal, ou seja, fazer uma cópia dele no Modal?

Comment: sim, exatamente...

Answer (score 1):

Faz assim, se for apenas para apresentar o reapeater, sem nenhuma ação, você pode copiar o html gerado em tempo de execução e jogar na sua div `.modal-body`.

Você primeiro pega o clientId gerado para seu repeater, depois faz um clone e joga na sua div, sem precisar criar um controler e o escambau.

```
var stormTrooper = $('#myRepeaterId').clone(); //Clona o html do objeto.
$('.modal-body').append(stormTrooper); //Renderiza o clone do repeater
```

Menos código, mais limpo.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo,
Poderia resolver teu problema talvez se você colocasse o Repeater dentro de um UserControl e usasse-o no lugar do Repeater atual e dentro de `<div class="modal-body">`...`</div>`. Isso resolveria o problema do layout igual, mas não da persistência (afinal ainda seriam instâncias diferentes). Para persistir os mesmos dados, o mais prático creio que seria ao clicar para exibir modal, copiar os valores dos campos internos (no caso, o DataSource) e preencher no do modal. O DataSource carregado seria sempre o mesmo objeto, passado para as duas instâncias de UserControl. Ao voltar para a tela do primeiro Repeater, o mesmo processo teria de ser feito de forma inversa. Isso supondo que os dois devem aparecer separadamente para o usuário, pois do contrário, a única forma de fazer o usuário digitar em um lugar e atualizar no outro seria colocando eventos de alteração em cada um dos campos e automaticamente preenchendo no outro (por code behind dando postback ou mesmo javascript).

Não estou certo quanto ao funcionamento da solução, espero ajudar.